# Стоит ли делать глобальной переменной HWND главного окна на Си?

Tags: c

В функции
`LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`
получаю `hwnd`, потом приходится передавать её во многие другие функции через параметры, а это загромождает код. Может, сделать глобальную переменную `Hwnd`, пусть другие функции используют её? А то я читал теорию, что глобальные переменные опасны, но в данном случае, возможно, это оправдано?

Comment: Они опасны только тем, что вы можете где то забыть, что она глобальная и ее поменять случайно. Так что назовите ее так, что бы точно знать, что она глобальная и что бы точно ни с чем другим не пересеклась (и с большими буквами). Просто `Hwnd` мне кажется слишком просто, легко перепутать с десятками других hwnd маленькими буквами. Лучше дайте более говорящее название, в котором будет отражено hwnd какого окна. И если она устанавливается в CALLBACK, будьте осторожны и не начните ее использовать до того как коллбак произошел.